# Keep Widget on top in Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have created this widget in the following window.
I would like it to stay on the top always like a toolbar.
Here's the kivy file code:

```
BoxLayout:
    height: "40dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    TextInput:
        id: search_box        
        size_hint_x: 25      
        multiline: False
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer myself! I kind of made a mistake in this part:

```
 pos_hint: {'top':1}
```

Here's the modified code:

```
BoxLayout:
    height: "40dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    TextInput:
        id: search_box        
        size_hint_x: 25      
        multiline: False
```